# Ng-submitted not being applied to form

Tags: angularjs

According to the docs, forms in angular should apply a "ng-submitted" class when submitted, but I'm not seeing that. In the linked jsfiddle below you can see that even after the submitted button is clicked, the class is not applied.

[The docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form)

[The jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joshdmiller/HB7LU/)

edit: I included some code here even though it is pointless, check out the jsfiddle above.

```
//this is the code i have in the jsfiddle, check it out there.
<form>
    <button type="submit">
</form>
```

What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Try using a code snippet, which is a new feature in Stack Overflow.  http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: I need to include some libraries though, so I don't think a snippet would be ideal.

Comment: You have forgotten to add the link to the jsFiddle, its quite hard to help

Comment: I didn't add it because SO has a rule against the link when I have no code in the question. Since there is no relevant code to include, I just let it out. After your comment, I decided to put in some dummy code to circumvent the rule.

Comment: Could you tell what you want to do with the "ng-submitted" class. And are you sure it's not "ng-submit" that you want to use ?

Comment: I was going to style based on the ng-submitted class. For instance: form.ng-submitted input.ng-invalid { border-color: red; }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the docs again. ng-submitted has been added in somewhere in angular 1.3. Your fiddle uses like 1.0.1.

**Edit:**

See

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/8056
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/108a69be17df5884d026c57b2be3235c576250fe